Keycloak integration identity provider Microsoft Entra ID with SAML SSO error Cookie not found after redirect
I have a problem with Keycloak, what I would like to do is integrate Microsoft Entra ID into my Keycloak to log in via SSO in SAML. I managed to configure a new federation of identity provider with Microsoft Entra ID, but now when I start the login procedure via Entra ID, when the process is finished and i finally redirect to keycloak to confirm the assertion i receive the following error:
We are sorry...
Cookie not found. Please make sure cookies are enabled in your browser.

Now I have a K8s cluster where I have deployed Keycloak behind an nginx ingress, here is the configuration:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-dev
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "http"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/x-forwarded-proto: "https"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: idp.keycloak.eu
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: /
            backend:
              service:
                name: keycloak-service
                port:
                  number: 8080
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - idp.keycloak.eu
      secretName: tls-secret

Here are the environment variables that I set on Keycloak as ConfigMap:
KC_TRANSACTION_XA_ENABLED=true
KC_LOG=console,file
KC_LOG_LEVEL=all
KC_DB_SCHEMA=keycloak_db
KC_HEALTH_ENABLED=true
KC_METRICS_ENABLED=true
KC_LOG_CONSOLE_COLOR=true
KC_LOG_CONSOLE_FORMAT=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n
KC_LOG_FILE=data/log/keycloak.log
KC_LOG_FILE_LEVEL=debug
KC_LOG_CONSOLE_OUTPUT=json
KC_PROXY=edge
PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL=https://idp.keycloak.eu
KC_HOSTNAME=https://idp.keycloak.eu
KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS=true
enter code here

Here are the configurations Identity Provider on Keycloak:

Here is the Microsoft side configuration:

This is the logs error that i received when Keycloak consume SAML assertion:

stamp":"2024-11-02T21:29:38.435899765Z","sequence":146745,"loggerClassName":"org.jboss.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.keycloak.cookie.DefaultCookieProvider","level":"TRACE","message":"Received
cookies: , path:
/realms/foo-tenant-id/broker/foo-cli-id/endpoint","threadName":"executor-thread-49","threadId":90,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"keycloak-deployment-7864845bb8-m6hrh","processName":"/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-21.0.5.0.10-3.el9.x86_64/bin/java","processId":1}
{"timestamp":"2024-11-02T21:29:38.435967261Z","sequence":146746,"loggerClassName":"org.jboss.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.keycloak.cookie.DefaultCookieProvider","level":"WARN","message":"Non-secure
context detected; cookies are not secured, and will not be available
in cross-origin POST
requests","threadName":"executor-thread-49","threadId":90,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"keycloak-deployment-7864845bb8-m6hrh","processName":"/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-21.0.5.0.10-3.el9.x86_64/bin/java","processId":1}
{"timestamp":"2024-11-02T21:29:38.437015506Z","sequence":146747,"loggerClassName":"org.jboss.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.keycloak.services.resources.SessionCodeChecks","level":"DEBUG","message":"Authentication
session not found. Trying to restart from
cookie.","threadName":"executor-thread-49","threadId":90,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"keycloak-deployment-7864845bb8-m6hrh","processName":"/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-21.0.5.0.10-3.el9.x86_64/bin/java","processId":1}
{"timestamp":"2024-11-02T21:29:38.437067022Z","sequence":146748,"loggerClassName":"org.jboss.logging.Logger","loggerName":"org.keycloak.protocol.RestartLoginCookie","level":"DEBUG","message":"KC_RESTART
cookie doesn't
exist","threadName":"executor-thread-49","threadId":90,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"keycloak-deployment-7864845bb8-m6hrh","processName":"/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-21.0.5.0.10-3.el9.x86_64/bin/java","processId":1}
{"timestamp":"2024-11-02T21:29:38.442348712Z","sequence":146749,"loggerClassName":"org.jboss.logmanager.Logger","loggerName":"freemarker.cache","level":"FINE","message":"Couldn't
find template in cache for "error.ftl"("en_US", UTF-8, parsed);
will try to load
it.","threadName":"executor-thread-49","threadId":90,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"keycloak-deployment-7864845bb8-m6hrh","processName":"/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-21.0.5.0.10-3.el9.x86_64/bin/java","processId":1}
{"timestamp":"2024-11-02T21:29:38.443470293Z","sequence":146750,"loggerClassName":"org.jboss.logmanager.Logger","loggerName":"freemarker.cache","level":"FINE","message":"TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("error_en_US.ftl"):
Not
found","threadName":"executor-thread-49","threadId":90,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"keycloak-deployment-7864845bb8-m6hrh","processName":"/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-21.0.5.0.10-3.el9.x86_64/bin/java","processId":1}
{"timestamp":"2024-11-02T21:29:38.443718151Z","sequence":146751,"loggerClassName":"org.jboss.logmanager.Logger","loggerName":"freemarker.cache","level":"FINE","message":"TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("error_en.ftl"):
Not
found","threadName":"executor-thread-49","threadId":90,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"keycloak-deployment-7864845bb8-m6hrh","processName":"/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-21.0.5.0.10-3.el9.x86_64/bin/java","processId":1}
{"timestamp":"2024-11-02T21:29:38.444028205Z","sequence":146752,"loggerClassName":"org.jboss.logmanager.Logger","loggerName":"freemarker.cache","level":"FINE","message":"TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("error.ftl"):
Found","threadName":"executor-thread-49","threadId":90,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"keycloak-deployment-7864845bb8-m6hrh","processName":"/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-21.0.5.0.10-3.el9.x86_64/bin/java","processId":1}
{"timestamp":"2024-11-02T21:29:38.444119306Z","sequence":146753,"loggerClassName":"org.jboss.logmanager.Logger","loggerName":"freemarker.cache","level":"FINE","message":"Loading
template for "error.ftl"("en_US", UTF-8, parsed) from
"jar:file:/opt/keycloak/lib/lib/main/org.keycloak.keycloak-themes-26.0.5.jar!/theme/base/login/error.ftl"","threadName":"executor-thread-49","threadId":90,"mdc":{},"ndc":"","hostName":"keycloak-deployment-7864845bb8-m6hrh","processName":"/usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-21.0.5.0.10-3.el9.x86_64/bin/java","processId":1}

This is the error request:

Do you have a solution?
Thank you
